# Excel - Array Formula Extend

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this array formula which works fine

```
=IF(ROWS(K$62:K62)>COUNTIF(accounts_table[§],"<>J"),"",INDEX(accounts_table[Account Name],SMALL(IF(accounts_table[§]<>"J",ROW(accounts_table[§])-ROW(Ledger!$H$17)+1),ROWS($K$62:K62))))
```

However, I need to extend this for multiple COUNTIF Criteria:

```
accounts_table[§],"<>J"
accounts_table[§],"<>T"
accounts_table[§],"<>P"
```

I haven't been successful in doing this. I have tried this but doesn't work:

```
=IF(OR(ROWS(K$62:K62)>COUNTIF(accounts_table[§],"<>J"),ROWS(K$62:K62)>COUNTIF(accounts_table[§],"<>T")),"",INDEX(accounts_table[Account Name],SMALL(IF(OR(accounts_table[§]<>"J",accounts_table[§]<>"T"),ROW(accounts_table[§])-ROW(Ledger!$H$17)+1),ROWS($K$62:K62))))
```

Comment: MULTIPLE COUNTIF criteria...Potentially sounds like you need to use COUNTIFS which uses multiple criteria in an AND fashion.  All criteria must be true for it to be counted.

Comment: I tried that to no avail.. I presume the COUNTIFS at the beginning of the function needs to be the same as the COUNTIFS at the end of the function ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two adjustments to the formula:

(1) I was talking total rubbish previously, it is correct that the easiest thing to do is to use Countifs. You could subtract the two separate counts of J and T from the total, but it's longer.

(2) You can't use AND or OR in array formulas - they only give you one result for the entire array instead of iterating over the cells like you want them to. Instead you have to use multiply (*) or add (+). Here you are trying to include cells which are both not equal to J and not equal to T, so again you need AND logic, therefore you want to multiply.

```
=IF(ROWS(K$62:K62)>COUNTIFS(accounts_table[§],"<>J",accounts_table[§],"<>T"),"",INDEX(accounts_table[Account Name],SMALL(IF((accounts_table[§]<>"J")*(accounts_table[§]<>"T"),ROW(accounts_table[§])-ROW(Ledger!$H$2)+1),ROWS(K$62:$K62))))
```

[image]

Extending it to more variables is left as an exercise for the reader...unless you have a real lot of values to exclude in which case another approach might be needed.

Comment: hmm.. I have tried this solution and although it sounds promising, it's not returning the correct result.

Comment: Is it possible to give us a screenshot and/or test data to try and diagnose it?